# Very slow execution when calling function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two functions. The second function uses the output from the first function.

One is:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fp_splitfactor;
CREATE FUNCTION fp_splitfactor_price (id CHAR(8), startdate DATE)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
DECLARE splitfactor FLOAT;
SELECT IFNULL(EXP(SUM(LOG(f.p_split_factor))),1) INTO splitfactor
FROM fp_v2_fp_basic_splits AS f
WHERE f.fsym_id = id AND f.p_split_date > startdate AND f.p_split_date < NOW();
RETURN splitfactor; 
END$$
DELIMiTER ;
```

Second one is:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fp_splitadjprice;
CREATE FUNCTION fp_splitadjprice (id CHAR(8), startdate DATE)
RETURNS FLOAT 

BEGIN
DECLARE splitfactor FLOAT;
DECLARE splitadjprice FLOAT;
DECLARE spinofffactor FLOAT;

SET splitfactor = 1.0;

SELECT fp_splitfactor(id, startdate) INTO splitfactor;

SELECT (p_price * splitfactor) INTO splitadjprice
FROM fp_v2_fp_basic_prices
WHERE fsym_id = id AND p_date = startdate;

RETURN splitadjprice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I then try to exectute a query as the following:

```
SELECT 
p.fsym_id, 
b.p_co_sec_name_desc AS Company_Name,
b.region AS Region,
p.p_date,
p.p_price AS Unadjusted_Price,
fp_splitadjprice(p.fsym_id,p_date) AS Adjusted_Price
FROM
fp_v2_fp_basic_prices p
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT r2.region, b2.p_co_sec_name_desc, b2.fsym_id
        FROM  fp_v2_fp_sec_coverage b2
        LEFT JOIN sym_v1_sym_region r2 ON b2.fsym_id = r2.fsym_id
        WHERE r2.region = "EUR") b
        ON b.fsym_id =p.fsym_id
```

So basically my query calls the second function, which then calls the first function in order to return a value to the query. The execution is extremely slow though, but I do not understand why that is the case?

Comment: your query call recursively other query  .. this could be the reason for the slow execution  .. looking to the code  .. could be that you can get your result using only query an not function (that recursively perform query ) .. you should add  a proper (simple) data sample and the expected  resultt ..

Comment: @scaisEdge hmm, I will try to see if I can add a dataset. But I can't be the first one who has called functions from functions in MySQL before I reckon?

Comment: Yes  you are not the firts  .. nested  function are normally used but if for each row you select  you invoke a function that perform select  .. and so  on .. the performance  can't be good..In SQL an approach based on the Set Theory is usually better that an algortmic approach  ..

Comment: Well, when I perform a query calling only 1 function it is also extremely slow. This function has a datetime value though, but it is slow even when I limit the output to 10 rows. That does not make sense to at all?

Comment: so is only the query at the bottom of the question that is low ..  ?  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Creating the functions takes 0,1 sec. If I replace the function in the query with the first function fp_splitfactor, the query runs in 0,1 sec. If I have the second function instead it runs forever. Given the simplicity of function 2, that should never happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the slow execution was entire due to MySQL workbench not handling large datasets well. Once I migrated everything to BigQuery on Google Cloud everything worked perfectly.

STAY AWAY FROM CALLING FUNCTIONS ON LARGE DATASETS IN MySQL Workbench!